# JavaFX: Setting a border within a rectangle to keep the width and height

Tags: java, javafx

So, I have a grid of rectangles in my scene and I want to give it a border to visually seperate it to the others. I am currently using `grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);` and that works fine, but I am sure this isn't supposed to be used for that.

I tried setting a border with `nodes[j][i].setStroke(Color.BLACK);` and this works too, but now my whole grid is getting a lot bigger because it's drawing the border on the outside of the rectangle and therefore resizing it.

Is there a way to draw a border/stroke inside of a rectangle to keep the transformation?
I already looked up the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html) but there isn't such a function.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setStrokeType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#setStrokeType-javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType-) for your rectangles to draw the border inside using [`StrokeType.Inside`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/StrokeType.html#INSIDE):

```
nodes[j][i].setStrokeType(StrokeType.Inside);
```